# #Pentaho BI: stop user from Logging in after X incorrect attempts on Pentaho bi 6.0

Tags: pentaho

stop user from Logging in after X incorrect attempts.

I want to display custom message rather than the standard pentaho error login message

Comment: In the bset of my knowlege, that is not in the standard Spring configuration, so you'll have to code in java. What kind of security (Build-in, LDAP, JDBC,.. ) are you using ?

Comment: We are getting user information using JDBC

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the authenticate(Authentication) method to count the number of incorrect attempts.

The class is defined in the applicationContext-spring-security-jdbc.xml which is the pentaho-solution folder. if you did not change the default setup, it is the class org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.We have changed the defualt setup and using JDBC method for authentication. I have a question. I am not sure about the class. can you provide details about that class. Is it "org.springframework.security.providers.AuthenticationProvider" or org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"

Comment: Good question for which I never remember the answer without testing a bit. Put a log.info("Hello, it's me") on the classes and look into the pentaho.log. If you need help to setup the logging request a new question, so that get reputation when I answer to edit the  tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/classes